# ArcObjects SDK's for .net free download

Tags: sdk, arcobjects

Anyone can suggest where I can freely download Arc-Objects SDK's for Arc GIS 10.2 version?

Answer (score 0):

There is no legal way to download the ArcObjects SDK without paying for it.

You can purchase the EDN, but it's absurdly expensive.  The best options are to work for a company that pays for a license or use open-source GIS.

Answer (score 0):

There is one legal way, and that is to request a Free 60-day trial of ArcGIS Desktop from the [ESRI website](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/free-trial).  If you call them sometimes they can extend the trial but you must request that up front.

Note that the free trial will only be available for the current release and not for past versions.  The ArcObjects SDK is included with the ArcGIS Desktop installation media.